# Cosmos DB consistency

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

What is consistency within a region where the write has happened if an "eventual" consistency is chosen?

If I need a regional strong consistency only, which option should be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need strong reads within the primary region, you should pick either strong or bounded staleness consistency.

Comment: Are writes always happens in primary region first? If there is Region1 (primary) with WebApp1 and Region2 with WebApp2 and WebApp2 writes to DB and eventual consistency is chosen, will WebApp2 see the changes immediately? I don't expect WebApp1 to see changes instantly.

Comment: Writes happen in primary region first, but there are no guarantees for the order in which you'll read with eventual consistency.